# angularjs ng-option blank option instead preselected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm having a problem with display a preselected value as the selected option in my select element. Here goes the code

```
<select ng-model="data.company" ng-options="company as company.name for company in companies"></select>


$scope.companies =[{
    id:1,
    name:"Company 1"
},
{
    id:2,
    name:"Company 2"
}];

$scope.data = {
    company:{
        id:2,
        name:"Company 2"
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i enter in the section the select gives me a blank option as default insted of showing me "Company 2". What im i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$scope.data = $scope.companies[1];`

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times already on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`track by`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-) in this case, as you are assigning object value to the `ng-model` directly. In this case what happens is, when you bind object directly to `data.company`(ng-model) track by expression checks company.id in that `ng-model` with the each `companies` element id. If any one gets match it pre-select that input.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="data.company" 
   ng-options="company as company.name for company in companies track by company.id">
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwBrKJ2i6tYbP4gCOMhI?p=preview)

Comment: Wow, this works, can you explain me why without track  it doesnt work?

Comment: You actually don't need to use track by if you set the value to the companies object as $scope.data = { company: $scope.companies[1] };  See my update to my answer below

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar Many Thanks. It's working and I learned the proper way to use the track by expression

Comment: @Scott did you looked at the link from the angular doc which is thwre in answer.??

Comment: @Scott Basically in your casr you are not using which is why it don't need track by..

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
 <select ng-model="data.company" ng-options="company.name for company in companies"></select>

  $scope.data = {
      company: $scope.companies[1];
  };
```

You want the value shown in the dropdown to be the company name and the object stored to be the company.

Comment: Still not working, i will do as regular with  
`<select ng-model="data.company.id" ng-options="company.ld as company.name for company in companies"></select>` i cant figure out  in this way (the first one) why is not working because the object is beign stored correctly.

Comment: Yes this is working too, but te $scope.data will be retrieved by the database so i cant overwrite that content. I appreciate your answer too. Thanks to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ng-init

```
<select ng-init="data.company= companies[0]" 
        ng-model="data.company" 
        ng-options="company as company.name for company in companies"></select>
```